# Problema com escopo de variável no método each

Tags: javascript, jquery, escopo-de-variáveis

Estou tendo problemas com atribuição a uma variável dentro de um each no jQuery.

```
(function(){
    var filters = $(".filter_check:checked");
    var hiddenFields = '';

    $.each(filters, function(){
        hiddenFields += "&" + $(this).data('param') + "=1";
    });

    console.log( hiddenFields );
})();
```

Na última linha, quando eu verifico a saída, vejo que a variável está exatamente como foi declarada lá em cima, uma string vazia. A atribuição/concatenação no .each não funcionou... Isso me parece ser um problema com escopo. Alguém saberia me dizer o que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Seu var filters tá pegando alguma coisa?

Comment: Acredito que não há nenhum checkbox/radio com a classe `filter_check` **selecionado**. Seu código não possue nenhum problema.

Comment: O filters tem elementos sim pessoal... Mais de 10 no total.

Comment: Você poderia postar o seu código HTML para que eu possa testar? Não entendi por que está acessando os valores dentro do each com $(this).data('param').

Answer (score 2):

O [`$.each`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) (ou `jQuery.each`) que você está usando é para arrays e objetos. Para coleções de elementos do DOM, use [`.each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) direto na coleção:

```
var filters = $(".filter_check:checked");
var hiddenFields = '';

filters.each(function(){
    hiddenFields += "&" + $(this).data('param') + "=1";
});

console.log( hiddenFields );
```

Mas tem um jeito mais fácil de fazer o que você quer, o [`serialize`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/):

```
var filters = $(".filter_check:checked");
console.log( filters.serialize() );
```

Isso vai funcionar como o seu código, **contanto que** os checkboxes em questão tenham o atributo `name` com valor igual ao seu `data-param`, e tenham `value` com valor `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Eu acredito que o seu código $.each está errado. Acabo de fazer um teste e funcionou:

```
$(function(){
    var response = "";
    var items = ['a','b','c'];

    $.each(items,  function(index, item){

        response += item;

    });

    console.log(response);

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vcqvjjhk/

tente assim:

```
(function(){
    var filters = $(".filter_check:checked");
    var hiddenFields = '';

    $.each(filters, function(i, filter){
        hiddenFields += "&" + filter.data('param') + "=1";
    });

    console.log( hiddenFields );
})();
```